# Is Kurapika still the spiders target after removing the boss nen?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

After removing the nen from the spider's boss placed by Kurapika, what does the spiders do next? Do they want to kill Kurapika for the trouble he made to the spiders? Also, what happened to Kurapika's revenge to the spiders? Seems they are on ceasefire.

Comment: where are you in the storyline? Are you still watching or did you already finish the story?

Comment: I already finished the anime and I've read the manga but only in the Chrollo and Hisoka fight. After that I didn't continue anymore. @Kjenos